# Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart. Kotlin Plugin not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm using eclipse and trying to add a kotlin plugin after installing them in the marketplace. But it seems it's not working even I followed a simple tutorial that it should work (https://www.kotlintutorialblog.com/run-kotlin-program-eclipse-ide/). I'm stuck in step 4 and 5. I need to know why this has happened. My eclipse is portable. I put it in my external driver instead of in the Program Files.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wAz1.png

My Eclipse version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)

Kotlin Plugin: 0.8.21

I want the kotlin plugin to work in eclipse that's all I wanted, thank you.

Comment: We need to see the **full** stack trace of that exception, as plain text, not images.

Comment: You might try https://github.com/bvfalcon/kotlin-eclipse-2021 (and be aware [of this](https://twitter.com/_Pyves/status/1314276928279511040)).